# Hide button xciptv activity_categories

Tags: applications

I have been tryin to remove or hide buttons on android app xciptv but can't seem to make them go away.  I have set the visibility of the app to "gone" but they are still visible.  I can maneuver the buttons into different locations but never hide.

Please help

Comment: Umm... how did you set the visibility of the app to "gone"? And how did you know the ID of the button? Were you tinkering with its source code or something?

Comment: I went into the res/layout/activity_categories file and located the name of the button via the name of the .png file and changed the visibility from visible to gone